# How to get Cartesian product in Python using a generator?

Tags: python, iteration, generator, cartesian-product

I'm trying to get the Cartesian product of multiple arrays but the arrays are pretty large and I am trying to optimize memory usage. I have tried implementing a generator by using the below code but it just returns that there is a generator at a certain location.

```
import itertools

x = [[1,2],[3,4]]

def iter_tools(*array):
    yield list(itertools.product(*array))

print(iter_tools(*x))
```

When I try the same code but with `return` instead of `yield` it works fine. How could I get the cartesian product by implementing a generator?

Comment: Your *generator materializes the whole product immediately* defeating the entire purpose. In **any** case, `itertools.product(*array)` **is already an efficient iterator**. There is no need to wrap it in an generator. So just use `itertools.product(*array)`. Your generator does work, **generator functions return generators**. It seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: @juanpa Thanks! I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61686211/4518341) partly based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to yield individual item from the cartesian product, you need to iterate over the product:

```
import itertools

x = [[1,2],[3,4]]

def iter_tools(*array):
    for a in itertools.product(*array):
        yield a

for a in iter_tools(*x):
    print(a)
```

Comment: `itertools.product` is already an iterator, making this `iter_tools` pointless.

Answer (score 6):

Bottom line, `itertools.product` is already an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator). You don't need to write your own. (A [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) is a kind of iterator.) For example:

```
>>> x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> p = itertools.product(*x)
>>> next(p)
(1, 3)
>>> next(p)
(1, 4)
```

---

Now, to explain, it seems like you're misunderstanding something fundamental. A generator function returns a [generator iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator). That's what you're seeing from the print:

```
>>> iter_tools(*x)
<generator object iter_tools at 0x7f05d9bc3660>
```

Use `list()` to cast an iterator to a list.

```
>>> list(iter_tools(*x))
[[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]]
```

Note how it's a nested list. That's because your `iter_tools` yields one list then nothing else. On that note, that part makes no sense because casting `itertools.product` to a list defeats the whole purpose of an iterator - [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). If you actually wanted to yield the values from an iterator, you would use `yield from`:

```
def iter_tools(*array):
    yield from itertools.product(*array)
```

In this case `iter_tools` is pointless, but if your actual `iter_tools` is more complex, this might be what you actually want.

See also:

- [what's the difference between yield from and yield in python 3.3.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35518986/4518341)
- [How to Use Generators and yield in Python - Real Python](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)

---

*This answer is partly based on [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61685177/how-to-get-cartesian-product-in-python-using-a-generator#comment109111442_61685177)*

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a generator is that you don't do all the calculation at the same time, as you do with your call `list(itertools.product(*array))`. So what you want to do is *generate* the results one by one. For example like this:

```py
def iter_tools(*array):
    for i in array[0]:
        for j in array[1]:
            yield (i, j)
```

You can then do something with each resulting tuple like this:

```py
for tup in iter_tools(*x):
    print(tup)
```

Of course you can easily adapt the generator so that it yields each row or columns per call.

Or if you are happy with what itertools provides:

```py
for i in itertools.product(*x):
    print(i)
```

What you need depends on your use-case. Hope I could help you :)