# What's the difference between 'yield' and 'yield from' in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, generator, yield, coroutine, yield-from

I'm using the basic `yield` keyword a lot in my code to build generators and coroutines...

While searching for various `yield` related solutions on the web, I also found the `yield from` syntax. Both are used in generators.

I don't feel that I'm missing a feature here, so how does `from` tweek the basic `yield`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In practice, what are the main uses for the new "yield from" syntax in Python 3.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3)

Comment: You question is covered by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-is-the-function-of-the-yield-keyword/24944096#24944096) SO answers.