# Reyield a generator

Tags: python, generator

I would do this:

```
def walk(samples):
    for d in range(samples):
        yield d

def walk200():
    for d in walk(200):
        yield d
```

But actually what I want is this, to make the code shorter:

```
def walk200():
    reyield walk(200)
```

How do I do `reyield`?

Comment: Python 3.x: `yield from walk(200)`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye where x >= 3

Answer (score 6):

Python 3.3 and up:

```
def walk200():
    yield from walk(200)
```

For lower versions, you are stuck with the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

In your specific example, you can simply `return walk(200)`, and that will work in all python versions. `yield from` is only necessary in certain cases.

Comment: Interesting. Can you clarify? When and why is it necessary, and when not?

Comment: @dangonfast (1) if you have several yield statements in one function and you want to delegate only some of them to a different function, or more importantly (2) if you're using a generator as a coroutine, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3