# How to make a generator callable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a dataset from a CSV file with 784-bit long rows. Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

f = open("test.csv", "r")
csvreader = csv.reader(f)
gen = (row for row in csvreader)
ds = tf.data.Dataset()
ds.from_generator(gen, [tf.uint8]*28**2)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-4b244ea66c1d> in <module>()
     12 gen = (row for row in csvreader_pat_trn)
     13 ds = tf.data.Dataset()
---> 14 ds.from_generator(gen, [tf.uint8]*28**2)

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in from_generator(generator, output_types, output_shapes)
    317     """
    318     if not callable(generator):
--> 319       raise TypeError("`generator` must be callable.")
    320     if output_shapes is None:
    321       output_shapes = nest.map_structure(

TypeError: `generator` must be callable.
```

The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) said that I should have a generator passed to `from_generator()`, so that's what I did, `gen` is a generator. But now it's complaining that my generator isn't **callable**. How can I make the generator callable so I can get this to work?

**EDIT:**
I'd like to add that I'm using python 3.6.4. Is this the reason for the error?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `generator` argument (perhaps confusingly) should not actually be a generator, but a callable returning an iterable (for example, a generator function). Probably the easiest option here is to use a `lambda`. Also, a couple of errors: 1) [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) is meant to be called as a class factory method, not from an instance 2) the function (like a few other in TensorFlow) is weirdly picky about parameters, and it wants you to give the sequence of dtypes and each data row as `tuple`s (instead of the `list`s returned by the CSV reader), you can use for example `map` for that:

```
import csv
import tensorflow as tf

with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: map(tuple, csvreader),
                                        (tf.uint8,) * (28 ** 2))
```

Comment: thank you for simple and clear explanation

Answer (score 5):

Yuck, two years later... But hey! Another solution! :D

This might not be the cleanest answer but for generators that are more complicated, you can use a decorator. I made a generator that yields two dictionaries, for example:

```py
>>> train,val = dataloader("path/to/dataset")
>>> x,y = next(train)
>>> print(x)
{"data": [...], "filename": "image.png"}

>>> print(y)
{"category": "Dog", "category_id": 1, "background": "park"}
```

When I tried using the `from_generator`, it gave me the error:

```
>>> ds_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    iter(mm),
    ({"data":tf.float32, "filename":tf.string},
    {"category":tf.string, "category_id":tf.int32, "background":tf.string})
    )
TypeError: `generator` must be callable.
```

But then I wrote a decorating function

```
>>> def make_gen_callable(_gen):
        def gen():
            for x,y in _gen:
                 yield x,y
        return gen
>>> train_ = make_gen_callable(train)
```

```
>>> train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    train_,
    ({"data":tf.float32, "filename":tf.string},
    {"category":tf.string, "category_id":tf.int32, "background":tf.string})
    )

>>> for x,y in train_ds:
        break

>>> print(x)
{'data': <tf.Tensor: shape=(320, 480), dtype=float32, ... >,
 'filename': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, ...> 
}

>>> print(y)
{'category': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'Dog'>,
 'category_id': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>,
 'background': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'Living Room'>
}
```

But now, note that in order to iterate `train_`, one has to call it

```
>>> for x,y in train_():
        do_stuff(x,y)
        ...
```

Comment: `def make_gen_callable(_gen):...` parts really does the help. Key point is that  no arguments should be passed to `gen()` inside the `make_gen_callable()`. I don't need to make 2 different callable generators after adopting this.

Comment: You can do `yield from _gen` instead of `from x,y in _gen: yield x,y` (this is in general the preferred way to "pass through" a generator, as it has [several advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26109157/1782792) over a `for` loop). In this case, however, you could return the wrapped generator directly, so even something like `train_ = lambda: train` should work.

Answer (score 3):

[From the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator), which you linked:

> The `generator` argument must be a callable object that returns an
>   object that support the `iter()` protocol (e.g. a generator function)

This means you should be able to do something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import csv

with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    gen = lambda: (row for row in csvreader)
    ds = tf.data.Dataset()
    ds.from_generator(gen, [tf.uint8]*28**2)
```

In other words, the function you pass must produce a generator when called. This is easy to achieve when making it an anonymous function (a `lambda`).

Alternatively try this, which is closer to how it is done in the docs:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import csv


def read_csv(file_name="test.csv"):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield row

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(read_csv, [tf.uint8]*28**2)
```

(If you need a different file name than whatever default you set, you can use `functools.partial(read_csv, file_name="whatever.csv")`.)

The difference is that the `read_csv` function returns the generator object when called, whereas what you constructed is already the generator object and equivalent to doing:

```
gen = read_csv()
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, [tf.uint8]*28**2)  # does not work
```

Comment: Really? The example in the docs is a plain old generator function with `yield` not a function that `return`s a generator isn't it?

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, Chris. `gen` is a generator in the docs, not a function returning a generator.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, that is weird. So apparently a generator defined as a function also works.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I think the difference is that if you call that function (which is a generator) it returns the generator object. Whereas the `(x for x in ...)` is already the generator object itself.

Comment: Yes I understand the difference, but I honestly think the name should be clearer from `tensor`'s part like `from_generator_function`

Answer (score 0):

Pushing 5 years late, but given the two-hour-long headache this has caused me -- for those who want a more generalisable solution:

```py
class TFDatasetFromGenerator():

    def __init__(self, somearg=""):
        self.someparam = somearg
        '''etc; eg load S3 keys into a dataframe, s3keyDF'''
        self.DataFrame= s3keyDF

    def some_modifying_function(self, someotherarg=""):
        ''' do some stuff, 
        eg on self.someparam etc 
        or split self.DataFrame into train/test data refs etc
        '''
 
    def generate(self, arg1="", arg2=True, batch_size=128):
        return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
            self._generate(
                arg1=arg1,
                arg2=arg2,
                batch_size = batch_size
             ),
             (tf.float32, tf.float32),
             ((None,128,400,4), (None,1))
         )    
         ''' modify the data output shape as required; 
         we present x and y (input data and labels) as a tuple
         with both x and y being tf.float32
         x having the shape (batch_size,128,400,4)
         y having the shape (batch_size,1).
         '''

    def _generate(self, arg1="", arg2=True, batch_size=128):
        ''' _generate defines and returns the function `gen`.
        returning the function makes _generate a callable
        _generate can therefore be used as the first argument 
        to tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()
        '''

        def gen():

            '''do preprocessing, eg filter self.dataset 
            to return just training or test portions of the dataset    
            eg:
            '''
            if(arg1="train"):
                data_refs = list(
                    self.TrainDataFrame.data_referance.unique()
                )
                label_refs = list(
                    self.TrainDataFrame.label_refernce.unique()
                )
            ''' etc '''
            random.shuffle(data)
            

            ## get the sample count
            sample_count  = len(data_refs)

            while True:
                sample_index = 0

                while sample_index < sample_count:
                    start        = sample_index
                    end          = min(start + batch_size, sample_count)

                    # Load data from DataFames
                    x = data_refs[start: end]
                    y = label_refs[start: end]

                data = []
                for key in x:
                    ''' d = load your data '''
                    data.append(d)

                labels = []
                for key in y:
                    ''' l = load your labels '''
                    labels.append(l)
                

                sample_index += batch_size

                yield (np.array(data),np.array(labels))

        return gen
```

Hope this helps someone!