# Tensorflow TypeError: `generator` must be callable in tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am slightly losging my mind about a simple task. I want to implement a simple RandomForestClassifier on Images using the tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier (Gradient Boosted Tree is good enough although the difference is clear to me). I'm following the **https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/boosted_trees_model_understanding** guide. I swapped the

```
# Use entire batch since this is such a small dataset.
NUM_EXAMPLES = len(y_train)

def make_input_fn(X, y, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
  def input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X.to_dict(orient='list'), y))
    if shuffle:
      dataset = dataset.shuffle(NUM_EXAMPLES)
    # For training, cycle thru dataset as many times as need (n_epochs=None).
    dataset = (dataset
      .repeat(n_epochs)
      .batch(NUM_EXAMPLES))
    return dataset
  return input_fn
```

with my own function looking like this

```
# LOADING IMAGES USING TENSORFLOW
labels = ['some','fancy','labels']
batch_size = 32
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    data_format='channels_last',
    validation_split=0.1,
    dtype=tf.float32
)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    './images',
    classes=labels,
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True,
    subset='training',
    seed=42
)

valid_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    './images',
    classes=labels,
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False,
    subset='validation',
    seed=42
)

# THE SWAPPED FUNCTION:
NUM_FEATURES = 128 * 128
NUM_EXAMPLES = len(train_generator)

def make_input_fn(gen, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
    def input_fn():
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, (tf.float32, tf.int32))
        if shuffle:
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(NUM_EXAMPLES)
        # For training, cycle thru dataset as many times as need (n_epochs=None).
        dataset = (dataset
                   .repeat(n_epochs)
                   .batch(NUM_EXAMPLES))
        return dataset
    return input_fn


def _generator_(tf_gen):
    print(len(tf_gen))
    def arg_free():
        for _ in range(len(tf_gen)):
            X, y = next(iter(tf_gen))
            X = X.reshape((len(X), -1))
            print(X.shape)
            yield X, y
    return arg_free()


_gen = _generator_(train_generator)
print(callable(g_gen)) # returns Fals WHY?!
```

I dont understand why this is not working and why on earth nobody ever thaught about making a simple enough tutorial (or why I am not able to find it :D). If you are asking yourself, why I want to use the RandomForest and not regular Deep Learning aproaches. The RF is set by the supervising Authorithy as well as it has to be TF (and not e.g. sklearn).

Anyway, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: perhaps this answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280016/how-to-make-a-generator-callable

Comment: allready tried that without a success