# yield vs yield from when they are used for islice

Tags: python

I have a question regarding the differences between yield and yield from, particularly when they are used in combine with islice. Here is my code:

```
def get_table_row():
  iter_veh = get_data(fp_vehicle, vehicles_cols, Vehicles)
  iter_per = get_data(fp_personal, personals_cols, Personals)
  iter_emp = get_data(fp_employment, employments_cols, Employments)
  iter_upd = get_data(fp_update, updates_cols, Updates)
  yield from ((*v, *p, *e, *u) for v, p, e, u in zip(iter_veh, iter_per, iter_emp, iter_upd))

from itertools import islice
for row in islice(get_table_row(), 5):
  print(*row)
```

This will correctly print out 5 rows of records from the table.

HOWEVER, if I use the following code:

```
def get_table_row():
  iter_veh = get_data(fp_vehicle, vehicles_cols, Vehicles)
  iter_per = get_data(fp_personal, personals_cols, Personals)
  iter_emp = get_data(fp_employment, employments_cols, Employments)
  iter_upd = get_data(fp_update, updates_cols, Updates)
  yield ((*v, *p, *e, *u) for v, p, e, u in zip(iter_veh, iter_per, iter_emp, iter_upd))

from itertools import islice
for row in islice(get_table_row(), 5):
  print(*row)
```

This will lead to print out of all rows. The only difference here is yield from vs. yield. Need a explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Does the differing outcome not demonstrate what the difference is? `yield from something` is basically `for thing in something: yield thing`, in simple cases.

Comment: Read the differences between `yield` and `yield from`.

Answer (score 1):

A bare `yield` provides its argument. A `yield from` provides elements *from* its argument.

```
yield (1, 2, 3) # provide entire tuple at once
yield from (1, 2, 3) # provide elements from the tuple
```

You can think of `yield from` as `yield` plus iteration:

```
yield from (1, 2, 3)
# iteration style 
for element in (1, 2, 3):
    yield element
```

Note that `yield from` does more than iteration: it bridges between its argument and the calling scope. Signals such as `generator.close()` are passed on automatically, instead of needing manual propagation.

Answer (score 1):

The `yield from` statement (greatly simplified) will `yield` every item from the given iterator. Whereas the `yield` statement will `yield` a single value.

For this particular use-case you could replace `yield from` with the following lines of code:

```
for value in generator:
    yield value
```

Here's some more info about what `yield from` can do: [In practice, what are the main uses for the new "yield from" syntax in Python 3.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3)