# Python 3 iterable lazy chunk fetch

Tags: python, python-3.x, lazy-loading

is there standard method that able to lazy fetch next chunk of data and yield it by elements

currently I'm fetching all of chunks and chain them with itertools

```
def list_blobs(container_name:str, prefix:str):    
    chunks = []
    next_marker=None
    while True:
        blobs = blob_service.list_blobs(container_name, prefix=prefix, num_results=100, marker=next_marker)
        next_marker = blobs.next_marker
        chunks.append(blobs)
        if not next_marker:
            break

    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(chunks)
```

what is the "lazy" version of list_blobs fetcher?

Comment: This question would be much easier to answer with a [MCVE]. We can't run the code you posted or verify our solutions after modifying it. Since the solution should presumably work for any iterable, why not post a sample that runs without further context such as global variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `chunks.append(blobs)` with `yield from blobs`, and get rid of the `return` and `chunks` `list` entirely:

```
def generate_blobs(container_name:str, prefix:str):
    next_marker = None
    while True:
        blobs = blob_service.list_blobs(container_name, prefix=prefix, num_results=100, marker=next_marker)
        next_marker = blobs.next_marker
        yield from blobs
        if not next_marker:
            break
```

That converts the function to a generator function that yields a single item at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`yield from`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3) :

```
def list_blobs(container_name:str, prefix:str):
    next_marker = True
    while next_marker:
        blobs = blob_service.list_blobs(container_name, prefix=prefix, num_results=100, marker=next_marker)
        next_marker = blobs.next_marker
        yield from blobs
```

Comment: next_marker = True
while next_marker:

too much optimization, Azure requires None. anyway, thank you for a hint

Answer (score 0):

@ShadowRanger, @Kasrâmvd thank you very much

@timgeb, full code of lazy itarable through Azure BlobStorage

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import Blob
from typing import Iterable, Tuple

def blob_iterator(account:str, account_key:str, bucket:str, prefix:str)-> Iterable[Tuple[str, str]]:
    blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account, account_key=account_key) 

    def list_blobs(bucket:str, prefix:str)->Blob:
        next_marker = None
        while True:
            blobs = blob_service.list_blobs(bucket, prefix=prefix, num_results=100, marker=next_marker)
            yield from blobs
            next_marker = blobs.next_marker
            if not next_marker:
                break

    def get_text(bucket:str, name:str)->str:
        return blob_service.get_blob_to_text(bucket, name).content

    return ( (blob.name, get_text(bucket, blob.name)) for blob in list_blobs(bucket, prefix) )


it = blob_iterator('account', 'account_key', 'container_name', prefix='AA')
```