# Calling function that yields from a pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest

In my unit tests, I have two very similar fixtures, and I was hoping to break out some of the functionality into a helper function of some kind. Given my understanding of how `yield` produces generators, I don't feel like this should cause any kind of problem. `my_fixture_with_helper`, should just return the generator that `fixture_helper` produces.

```py
import pytest


def fixture_helper():
    print("Initialized from the helper...")
    yield 26
    print("Tearing down after the helper...")


@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture_with_helper():
    return fixture_helper()


@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    print("Initialized from the fixture...")
    yield 26
    print("Tearing down after the fixture...")


def test_nohelper(my_fixture):
    pass


def test_helper(my_fixture_with_helper):
    pass
```

However, if I run `pytest --capture=no`, I get the following

```
test_foo.py Initialized from the fixture...
.Tearing down after the fixture...
.
```

I would expect "Initialized from the helper" and "Tearing down after the helper" to get printed, but it does not, and I cannot figure out why. Why does this not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `yield from` to be able to pass the generator through properly. Otherwise the generator object will be returned, which isn't recognized by `pytest` as a generator.

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture_with_helper():
    yield from fixture_helper()
```

Much more information about `yield from` can be found at [this stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3)

Comment: Why would it not be recognizable? Doesn't yield normally return a generator?

Comment: Aha! My version doesn't allow pytest to understand that it's a generator function (see `inspect.isgeneratorfunction`) Thank you!