# How can I rewrite this function with list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to use a list comprehension to call this function.

```
def perfect_squares(limit):
    value = 1
    while value < limit:
        yield value*value
        value += 1

foo = perfect_squares(1000)
for i in range(6):
    print(next(foo))
```

Comment: This is not grammatical Python. Please make sure your code is a [example]. Notably, your indentation is wrong, and will generate an error.

Comment: @taseikyo I reverted your edit because I'm pretty sure the function's not supposed to be recursive, but let's let OP fix it.

Comment: @wrkyle Writing a function is not the same as calling a function. Please don't make edits that change the meaning of a post. You could edit your edit to remove that change.

Comment: @Amadan is right, please fix your code. If it helps, check out [Formatting help - code](/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you’re looking for a comprehension so the function still is a generator

```
def perfect_squares(limit):
    yield from (v*v for v in range(1,limit))
```

Or as returning a actual list using a list comprehension:

```
def perfect_squares(limit):
    return [v*v for v in range(1,limit)]
```

Comment: Is there advantage to `yield from genexpr` vs `return genexpr` in this context? (Serious question, I'm still new to `yield from`)

Comment: `yield from` is the same contextually as `for x in y: yield z` So yes the function would still be a generator vs being a regular function returning a generator.

Comment: I understand that; it's just that invoking either will still result in a generator object. `list(yield_from_fn())` is exactly the same as `list(loop_yield_fn())`. (Also, `yield from` is [not quite the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26109157/240443) as a yielding loop, though it's a good enough explanation in this context.) Never mind, I'm overthinking this. :P

Comment: @Amadan In this simple context, not really. But `yield from ... ` doesn't, you know, *return* from the function. You can write `def single_digits_twice(): yield from range(10); yield from range(10)`, which is considerably different from `def single_digits_twice(): return range(10); return range(10)` (which only yields the single-digit numbers once).

Comment: Note: the `yield from` expression was introduced in python 3.3 and is detailed in [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) it was added for a purpose as the return object from yielding is `<generator object perfect_squares at 0x116dd1200>` and returning a genexp is `<generator object perfect_squares.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x116dd13b8>`. So both perform the same while they do differ. In the end it’s down to how you plan to use it and/or code style.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using yield, you cannnot do this with list comprehension.
If you want to use list comprehension, you should produce the whole list first, and then print them instead.

Without yield, you can do it as follows:

```
power_of_2 = [x ** 2 for x in range(1, 1000)]
```

Comment: This is incorrect. List comprehension without square brackets creates a generator just like a function with `yield` does. These are equivalent: `def squares(): for i in range(5): yield i*i` and `(i * i for i in range(5))`. (Granted, it's called a "generator expression" and not really "list comprehension" then.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Amadan. Yes, I have answered w.r.t. the actual question which said "list comprehension".