# Python's equivalent to F#'s yield! (yield bang)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have the following code in F#:

```
let rec all_numbers_from k =
  yield k
  yield! all_numbers_from (k+1)
```

This code can be called as `all_numbers_from 0`, generating all numbers from 0 to infinity. I know Python also has a `yield` keyword, that seems to behave very much like F#'s `yield` operator. My question is if there's also some sort of equivalent to F#'s `yield!` operator?

Comment: It might help if you explain what F# `yield!` does. Taking a shot in the dark here: are you looking for [`yield from`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3)?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: it can be inferred from the above snippet, but I'll explain: `yield` returns a value, `yield! X` is roughly equivalent to doing an iteration over `X`, yielding all its values (lazily, of course).

Comment: Yeah, looks like `yield from`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380

Comment: @devouredelysium There's [an edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59601574/edit) you can use to add the explanation to your actual post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent Python feature would be  [`yield from`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3).

```py
def all_numbers_from(k):
  yield k
  yield from all_numbers_from(k+1)
```

However this would create a large number of chained generators, and is a poor implementation in Python. See [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59601649/119527) for a better alternative.

Answer (score 5):

While `yield from` is the construct you are looking for, defining this function (co)recursively is horribly inefficient in Python. Use iteration

```
def all_numbers_from(k):
    while True:
        yield k
        k = k + 1
```

or just use `itertools.count(k)`.