# How to count all elements in a tuple of tuples with dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have the following list:

lst= (1,(1,2), 3, (3,4), 1, 3)

and I want to use the dictionary function generate output that will count the number of times each value occurs such that it would look like this:

{1:3, 2:1, 3:3, 4:1}

I am lost on how to do this.
Thank you!

Below is my attempt:

```
def f(*args):
    for x in args:
        d = {x:args.count(x) for x in args}
    return d
```

Comment: How much nesting do you anticipate? Is it always a maximum of 1 tuple deep or can it be arbitrarily deep?

Comment: def f(*args):
    for x in args:
        d = {x:args.count(x) for x in args}
    return d

Comment: arbitrarily deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arbitrary depth tuples, you could use a recursive function for flattening:

```
def flatten_nested_tuples(tuples):
    for tup in tuples:
        if isinstance(tup, tuple):
            yield from flatten_nested_tuples(tup)
        else:
            yield tup
```

The `yield from x` syntax is equivalent to the `for item in x: yield item`. Its just a shorter way to create generators. You can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3/26109157#26109157) for more information about generators and the `yield` keyword.

To count we can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the flattened tuples:

```
from collections import Counter

lst= (1,(1,2), 3, (3,4), 1, 3)

print(Counter(flatten_nested_tuples(lst)))
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({1: 3, 3: 3, 2: 1, 4: 1})
```

**Note:** `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so you can treat it like a regular dict.

If you want to count yourself without any modules, you have to do the `0` initializing yourself:

```
counts = {}
for item in flatten_nested_tuples(lst):
    counts[item] = counts.get(item, 0) + 1

print(counts)
# {1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 1}
```

Or without using [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
counts = {}
for item in flatten_nested_tuples(lst):
    if item not in counts:
        counts[item] = 0
    counts[item] += 1

print(counts)
# {1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm trying to figure it out specifically using the dictionary function.

Comment: @Irk889 `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`.

Comment: I want to do this without importing any modules.

Comment: @Irk889 Added solutions without modules.