# What is the difference between returning an iterator, yielding in a for loop and yielding from an iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, yield

Consider the following three functions:

```
def return_iter(iterable):
    return iter(iterable)

def for_loop_yield(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        yield item

def yield_from_iter(iterable):
    yield from iterable
```

All of them produce the same results when looped over:

```
>>> prog_langs = ['python', 'java', 'c++']
>>> for lang in return_iter(prog_langs):
...     print(lang)
python
java
c++
>>> for lang in for_loop_yield(prog_langs):
...     print(lang)
python
java
c++
>>> for lang in yield_from_iter(prog_langs):
...     print(lang)
python
java
c++
```

What is the difference through?

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In practice, what are the main uses for the new "yield from" syntax in Python 3.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3)