# Generator comprehension using another generator

Tags: python, generator, yield

I am trying to write a method that returns a `Generator`. The end result of these two methods is to get a combination of two lists in the form: `'A #1', 'B #1', ..., 'F #9'`

```
FLATS = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

def generate_nums() -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    prefix = '#'
    for num in range(10):
        code = ''.join([prefix, str(num)])

        yield code

def generate_room_numbers() -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    room_nums = generate_nums()

    yield (' '.join([flat_name, room_num]) for room_num in room_nums for flat_name in FLATS)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = generate_room_numbers()
    result = next(result) # I hate this. How do I get rid of this?
    for room in result:
        print(room)
```

This gives me the correct outcome. Although, my annoyance is the line `result = next(result)`. Is there a better way to do this? I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26109157/3491653) answer as well as the `yield from` syntax but I can barely understand generators enough as it is.

Comment: `code = ''.join([prefix, str(num)])` is a really wordy way of writing `prefix + str(num)`, and honestly probably more readable as `f"{prefix}{num}`

Comment: I assumed it'd be more efficient than using `+` and `f'{x}'`, no?

Comment: Why are you using `yield` in `generate_room_numbers`? Just use `return` and you don't need to use `next`

Comment: No, it isn't, not for two strings. `''.join` is efficient for joining many strings in a container with a separator

Comment: This appears to be a customer generator.  Why can you not simply use the base generator expression as your loop iterator?  Do you need to reset and reuse a very large generator sequence for your actual application?  If not, a simple loop seems to be the better implementation.

Comment: The whole thing can just be replaced by `[f'{flat} #{num}' for num in range(10) for flat in FLATS]` (or a generator expression if you prefer)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The OP can correct me if I'm wrong, but I am assuming that `generate_nums` is meant to represent something which, for whatever reason, does indeed need to be a generator, and that the question is fundamentally about how to wrap a generator in a loop inside another generator, rather than whether the specific `generate_nums` in this application would be more efficiently implemented using `return`.

Comment: @alaniwi yes - the `generate_nums()` needs to be a generator because, in reality, it generates a really huge list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be best if the `yield` statement is put inside an explicit loop rather than trying to yield a generator.

Your `generate_room_numbers` should look like this:

```
def generate_room_numbers():
    for flat_name in FLATS:
        room_nums = generate_nums()
        for room_num in room_nums:    
            yield (' '.join([flat_name, room_num]))
```

Note that the `generate_nums()` is called *inside* the `flat_name` loop, because you cannot repeatedly iterate over the same iterator that it returns; after iterating through it, it is exhausted and `generate_nums` will raise `StopIteration` every time (so that iterating produces an empty sequence).

*(If `generate_nums` is expensive, then you could of course do `nums = list(generate_nums())` outside the `flat_name` loop and then iterate over that inside the loop, but if this requires potentially a lot of memory, then it could defeat much of the point in using a generator in the first place.)*

The rest of your code is unchanged except that the `result = next(result)` in the main code is removed, but for convenience, here is the whole thing:

```
FLATS = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

def generate_nums():
    prefix = '#'
    for num in range(10):
        code = ''.join([prefix, str(num)])

        yield code

def generate_room_numbers():
    for flat_name in FLATS:
        room_nums = generate_nums()
        for room_num in room_nums:    
            yield (' '.join([flat_name, room_num]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = generate_room_numbers()
    # result = next(result)  <<==== NOT NEEDED ANY MORE
    for room in result:
        print(room)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generator expression and a f-string:

```
FLATS = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
room_numbers = (f'{letter} #{i}' for i in range(1, 10) for letter in FLATS)

for room in room_numbers:
    print(room)
```

Output:

```
A #1
B #1
C #1
.
.
.
D #9
E #9
F #9
```