# Prime number generators using Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, generator, primes

This python code generates prime numbers using Sieve's technique. I am having trouble understanding the code in particular the `yield from` parts. How to trace such a code or make it simpler to understand.  This code is from the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jwV3zxXc8E) from Computerphile Youtube channel about laziness in python.

```py
def nats(n):
    yield n
    yield from nats(n+1)


def sieve(s):
    n = next(s)
    yield n
    yield from sieve(i for i in s if i%n != 0)
    
    
p = sieve(nats(2))

next(p) # generates prime numbers 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ........
```

Comment: you could start by adding print statements.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python example from Computerphile about yield and yield from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64781874/15187728)

Comment: Am I wrong, or is `nats` equivalent to [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)?