# How can I make function that takes a list as input and returns the sum?

Tags: python, list, function, input, sum

I want to make a function that takes a list as input and returns the **sum of integers, real numbers, and complex numbers among the elements of the list.** As elements of the list, data type objects other than integers, real numbers, and complex numbers are excluded when calculating the sum.

So I wrote the code like this way

```
def number_sum(lst):
    total = 0
    for e in lst:
        if type(e) == int or type(e) == float or type(e) == complex:
            total += e
    return total

x1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]                     # 25
x2 = ["abc", [3, 5], 3.5, 2+3j, 4.5, 10] # 20 + 3j
x3 = []                                  # 0

print(number_sum(x1))
print(number_sum(x2))
print(number_sum(x3))
```

but I want I can take the x1, x2, x3 lists in input. How can I fix it?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake! x2's result is # 20 + 3j.

Comment: you will also have a problem with any nested lists as within x2, an elif statement to recursively call number_sum would solve this

Comment: Is the result 20 + 3j or 28 + 3j?

Comment: 20 + 3j is the result!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numbers.Number`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number) to check if a value is a number. From the documentation:

> The root of the numeric hierarchy. If you just want to check if an
> argument x is a number, without caring what kind, use isinstance(x,
> Number).

**Code**

```
import numbers


def number_sum(lst):
    def get_numbers(l):
        """Generator that returns a flatten view a list"""
        for e in l:
            if isinstance(e, numbers.Number):
                yield e
            elif isinstance(e, (tuple, list)):
                yield from get_numbers(e)

    return sum(get_numbers(lst))


x1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
x2 = ["abc", [3, 5], 3.5, 2 + 3j, 4.5, 10]

print(number_sum(x1))
print(number_sum(x2))
```

**Output**

```
25
(28+3j)
```

Note that the function `get_numbers` is a generator that uses [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) and [`yield from`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3) to flatten and filter the nested list.  The result of `get_numbers` is then pass to the built-in function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to actually sum the numbers.

Answer (score -3):

you may use `x = input("Enter the List: ")` so that user can enter list in one line.
Import ast
If you want user to enter list as [1,2,3], then, use 
`import ast`
`x = input()`
`x = ast.literal_eval(x)`.
This will turn the string into a list.
finally your code will look like:

```
import ast

x = input("Enter the List: ")
x = ast.literal_eval(x)
```

Then, do the necessary function, that you want to do
Thanks to @Matthis and @S3DEV for improving suggesting the improvement

Comment: Might I suggest that you never use or advocate `eval` ever again until you read and understood "[Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)"?

Comment: I whole-heartedly support @Matthias comment. In fact, beat me to it.  Additionally, this *”If this answer solves your problem, kindly choose it as your answer”* is considered poor form.