# Combine two generators and preserve send method

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I have a generator that I can send values to using the `generator.send()` method. I'd like to add to this generator after it has been made and continue using the same functions to iterate through it. I tried `itertools.chain`, but that returns an iterator and I get an `AttributeError` when I try to send values to it.

How can I combine two generators and preserve the ability to send values to them?

Comment: Can you share the code you've written to define and make the generator?

Comment: What does "add to" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `yield from` (refer to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26109157/3767239) for more details):

```py
def multi_generator(*gens):
    for gen in gens:
        yield from gen
```