# Avoiding extra `next` call after `yield from` in Python generator

Tags: python, generator, coroutine, yield, yield-from

Please see the below snippet, run with Python 3.10:

```py
from collections.abc import Generator

DUMP_DATA = 5, 6, 7

class DumpData(Exception):
    """Exception used to indicate to yield from DUMP_DATA."""

def sample_gen() -> Generator[int | None, int, None]:
    out_value: int | None = None
    while True:
        try:
            in_value = yield out_value
        except DumpData:
            yield len(DUMP_DATA)
            yield from DUMP_DATA
            out_value = None
            continue
        out_value = in_value
```

My question pertains to the `DumpData` path where there is a `yield from`.  After that `yield from`, there needs to be a `next(g)` call, to bring the `generator` back to the main `yield` statement so we can `send`:

```py
def main() -> None:
    g = sample_gen()
    next(g)  # Initialize
    assert g.send(1) == 1
    assert g.send(2) == 2

    # Okay let's dump the data
    num_data = g.throw(DumpData)
    data = tuple(next(g) for _ in range(num_data))
    assert data == DUMP_DATA

    # How can one avoid this `next` call, before it works again?
    next(g)
    assert g.send(3) == 3
```

How can this extra `next` call be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `yield from` a tuple directly, the built-in `tuple_iterator` (which `sample_gen` delegates to) handles an additional "final value" `yield` before it terminates. It does not have a `send` method (unlike generators in general) and returns a final value `None` to `sample_gen`.

The behavior:

```py
yield from DUMP_DATA  # is equivalent to:
yield from tuple_iterator(DUMP_DATA)
```

```py
def tuple_iterator(t):
    for item in t:
        yield item
    return None
```

You can implement `tuple_iterator_generator`, with usage:

```py
try:
    in_value = yield out_value
except DumpData:
    yield len(DUMP_DATA)
    in_value = yield from tuple_iterator_generator(DUMP_DATA)
out_value = in_value
```

```py
def tuple_iterator_generator(t):
    in_value = None
    for item in t:
        in_value = yield item
    return in_value
```

Or just not use `yield from` if you don't want that behavior:

```py
try:
    in_value = yield out_value
except DumpData:
    yield len(DUMP_DATA)
    for out_value in DUMP_DATA:
        in_value = yield out_value
out_value = in_value
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator for a use case of that behavior.

Comment: IMO this is wrong. The `None` value is not coming from some tuple iterator. It is the value assigned in the line `out_value = None` after the `yield from`.

Comment: I made a test with a different value *before* leaving the comment. The answer by @GoodCoderBBoy states that too - independently from my test.

Comment: @VPfB Thanks for the correction, the explanation was wrong and I have fixed that. The code correctly demonstrates the behavior though.

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot of effort to go to, to remove a single line of code.

**Note that this is a bad solution if `DUMP_DATA` is a large object, or doesn't support slicing, because slicing will cause all of `DUMP_DATA` to be stored in memory, before being yielded, which defeats the point of using a generator.**

As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26109157/15081390, `yield from` "establishes a transparent bidirectional connection between the caller and the sub-generator". Calling `next(g)` terminates this and allows the loop to continue. In doing so it receives (and discards) `out_value`, which is set to `None` after `yield from DUMP_DATA`. In the OP's code, we can substitute this call to `next` for the last one when defining the variable `data`:

```py
data = tuple(next(g) for _ in range(num_data))
             ^^^^^^^
```

All that is needed is be able to detect the end of `DUMP_DATA`. If DUMP_DATA is a [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) (supports subscripting), then we can use `yield from DUMP_DATA[:i-1]` to `yield from` all but the last element, which will be yielded normally (by assigning `DUMP_DATA[-1]` to `out_value` and re-entering `sample_gen`'s normal loop). Thus, when the final line in `main` is called, the generator will respond normally.

```py
from collections.abc import Generator

DUMP_DATA = 5, 6, 7

class DumpData(Exception):
    """Exception used to indicate to yield from DUMP_DATA."""

def sample_gen() -> Generator[int | None, int, None]:
    out_value: int | None = None
    while True:
        try:
            in_value = yield out_value
        except DumpData:
            # yield length, but not before storing in var i
            yield (i := len(DUMP_DATA))

            # if length is more than one item, then yield the first n - 1 elements
            if i > 1:
                yield from DUMP_DATA[:i-1]

            # in case DUMP_DATA is of length 0, don't try to yield it
            if i:
                out_value = DUMP_DATA[-1]

            continue

        out_value = in_value
```

```py
def main() -> None:
    g = sample_gen()
    next(g)  # Initialize

    assert g.send(1) == 1
    assert g.send(2) == 2

    # Okay let's dump the data
    num_data = g.throw(DumpData)

    # the last call of next(g) exits the yield from state
    data = tuple(next(g) for _ in range(num_data))

    assert data == DUMP_DATA

    # no need to call next(g)
    assert g.send(3) == 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() # executes fine
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your inner generator in a "plain" generator which has the `send` method.
This will remove, for this level, the small optimizations of using `yield` from, since you are back to Python code iterating a generator and yielding a value - but that is the only way to accept the value `sent` by the next iteration after the inner generator is eaxhausted.

That said, it is straightforward:

```
...

def inner_gen(gen):
    for item in gen:
        incoming = yield item
    return incoming

def sample_gen() -> Generator[int | None, int, None]:
    out_value: int | None = None
    while True:
        try:
            in_value = yield out_value
        except DumpData:
            yield len(DUMP_DATA)
            out_value = yield from inner_gen(DUMP_DATA)
            continue
        out_value = in_value
...
def main() -> None:
    g = sample_gen()
    next(g)  # Initialize
    assert g.send(1) == 1
    assert g.send(2) == 2

    # Okay let's dump the data
    num_data = g.throw(DumpData)
    data = tuple(next(g) for _ in range(num_data))
    assert data == DUMP_DATA

    # This `send` value will be taken into the "inner_gen" ,
    # and used as the return value of the `yield from` expression.
    assert g.send(3) == 3
```

Of course, this only works because you know before hand the number of elements the `yield from` will produce, and call `send` after receiving the last value and before it stops with `StopIteration`. After a generator is exhausted, its return value (usually None) is already produced, and there is no way to pre-emptively "ask for a value" from the code driving a generator without yielding to it.