# Python does cursor execute load all data

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to query a large data (10 million rows) and try to prevent out of memory, but not familiar with Python and confused with different opinions regarding the execute(), cursor iterator and fetchone()

Am I right to assume that cursor.execute() does not load all data into memory and only when I call fetchone() then it will load 1 row of data

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection


def query():
    conn = MySQLConnection(host=conf['host'],
                                conf['port'],
                                conf['user'],
                                conf['password'],
                                conf['database'])
    cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLE') # 10 million rows
```

does this cursor iterator does the same with fetchone() ?

```
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

is my code snippet is safe to handle 10 million rows of data? if not, how can I safely iterate the data without out of memory?

Comment: I tested the memory usage, and it is as Milos Grujic answer, it does not load all data, however in the case of my code, as Nuno Mariz mentioned, if i use a buffered cursor (buffered=True) it will load all data into the memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html):

> The `fetchone()` method is used by `fetchall()` and `fetchmany()`. It is also used when a cursor is used as an iterator.

The following example shows two equivalent ways to process a query result. The first uses `fetchone()` in a while loop, the second uses the cursor as an iterator:

```py
# Using a while loop
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
  print(row)
  row = cursor.fetchone()

# Using the cursor as iterator
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
for row in cursor:
  print(row)
```

It also stated that:

> You must fetch all rows for the current query before executing new statements using the same connection.

If you are worried about performance issues you should use `fetchmany(n)` in a while loop until you fetch all of the results like so:

```py
'An iterator that uses fetchmany to keep memory usage down'
    while True:
        results = cursor.fetchmany(arraysize)
        if not results:
            break
        for result in results:
            yield result
```

This behavior adheres to [PEP249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), which describes how and which methods db connectors should implement. A partial answer is given in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189997/python-db-api-fetchone-vs-fetchmany-vs-fetchall).

Basically the implementation of `fetchall` vs `fetchmany` vs `fetchone` would be up to the developers of the library depending on the database capabilities, but it would make sense, in the case of `fetchmany` and `fetchone`, that the unfetched/remaining results would be kept server side, until requested by another call or destruction of cursor object.

**So in conclusion I think it is safe to assume calling execute method does not, in this case(mysqldb), dump all the data from the query to memory.**

Comment: if fetchmany() can help keep memory usage low, then isn't it better to use fetchone() instead?

Comment: That means you would be calling fetchone() function ten million times (one for each row), i'm not sure but it seems inefficient.

Comment: ah i see, so can I safely assume that if i use fetchmany(n) is the same with query with 'limit n' ? and that the execute() does not dump all data into the memory?

Comment: I think that if you iterate over an executed `cursor`, the results would be streamed one by one, this would of course be slower. If you use `fetchmany()` n results would be streamed from the server for your use, which is optimal..

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion is to use `from mysql.connector import connect`, which by the default will use the C extension (`CMySQLConnection`), instead of `from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection` (pure Python).

If you for some reason want to use the pure Python version, you can pass `use_pure=True` in `connect()`

The second suggestion is to paginate the results, if you use a buffered cursor, it will fetch the entire result set from the server. I don't know if you want that with 10M rows.

Here's some references:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorbuffered.html

Comment: ah i see, it fetched the entire data because i am using the buffered cursor. so if i am not using the buffered cursor, it should stream the data partially ?